# Should sockets be non-blocking to work with select in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, select, python-3.x, blocking

1. Should sockets be set to non-blocking when used with [`select.select`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/select.html#select.select) in Python?
2. What difference does it make if they are or aren't?

Occasionally I find that calling [`send`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) on a socket that returns sendable will block. Furthermore I find that [blocking](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking) sockets will generally send the whole buffer given (128 KiB). In non-blocking mode, sending will accept far fewer bytes (20-40 KiB compared with the example given earlier) and return quicker. I'm using [Python 3.1 on Lucid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/lucid-updates/python3.1).

Comment: Don't you mean "calling `recv` on a socket that returns readable"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer might be OS dependent unfortunately. I'm replying only regarding Linux.

I'm not aware of differences regarding blocking/non-blocking sockets in select, but on linux, the `select` system call man page has this in it 'BUGS' section:

> Under  Linux,  select()  may  report a
>   socket file descriptor as "ready for
>   reading", while nevertheless a
>   subsequent read blocks.  This could
>   for example happen when data has
>   arrived but upon examination has
>          wrong checksum and is discarded.  There may be other
>   circumstances in which a file
>   descriptor is spuriously reported as
>   ready.  Thus it may be safer to use
>   O_NONBLOCK on sockets that should not
>   block.

I doubt a python abstraction above that could "hide" this issue without side-effects.

As for the blocking write sending more data, that's expected. `send` will block until there is enough buffer space to pass your whole request down if the socket is blocking. If the socket is non-blocking, it only sends as much as can currently fit in the socket's send buffer.

Comment: A fantastic answer. Exactly what I was looking for.